# docker-compose build setup.py not found

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-image

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q7M2T.png)I am a newbie in docker and trying to practice building an image and running container here.

I have my file structure like the screenshot.

my goal is to process parse_arg_yay file with designated command in docker-compose file.

Below is my docker-compose file:

```
version : '3'
services:
  test:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    image: sample-test
    command: ['parse_arg_yay', "-p1", "20211211", "-p2", "koscom_etf_kr", "-p3","whatever"]
```

And below is my docker file:

```
FROM python:3.8-slim
MAINTAINER Jagn

ARG BUILD_VERSION=0.0.1

ADD . /opt/

RUN sed -i "s/version='\(.*\)'/version='"$BUILD_VERSION"'/g" /opt/setup.py \
    && cd /opt \
    && python setup.py sdist \
    && pip install dist/* \
    && cd / \
    && rm -rf /opt/*
```

and setup.py below:

```py
import os

from setuptools import find_packages, setup

with open(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'README.md')) as readme:
    README = readme.read()

with open(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'requirements.txt'), encoding='utf-8') as f:
    requirements = []
    for _requirement in f.read().splitlines():
        if not _requirement.startswith('git+https://') and not _requirement.startswith('--index-url'):
            requirements.append(_requirement)

setup(
    name='parse_arg',
    version='0.1.0',
    packages=find_packages(),
    py_modules=['parse_arg'],
    license='kkk',
    author='Jang',
    author_email='davis901@cc.co',
    description='',
    include_package_data=True,
    install_requires=requirements,
    scripts=[
        './parse_arg/bin/parse_arg_yay'
    ]
)
```

When I run the docker-compose build at the root directory, I am keep getting  setup.py not found. I am not sure how it got mixed up while I am copying entire directory into certain directory.

I have checked docker file, docker-compsoe file, requirements.txt file, and setup.py are in the same directory and copied requirements and setup file individually and fails.

Please help me out and let me know if I am misunderstanding

Comment: Can you check that the `docker-compose.yml`, `Dockerfile` and `setup.py` files are in the same directory ? I'm reproduced your setup but it works fine. Also, you can use the `WORKDIR` instruction to set the working directory to `/opt` so you could remove the `cd /opt` command, which would simplify debugging even more.

Comment: Does `pip install .` work better, without going through the extra step of creating the sdist?  I'm wondering if the `pip install dist/*` syntax is causing Pip to consider each individual file as a package name.

Comment: Hi Wassim, here are the paths for the files: